# Who can realize the nirvana easier?

Tags: nirvana

Who can realize the nirvana easier?As male one or female one?

Comment: Can the upvoter tell why such a question was upvoted?

Comment: Realizing Nirvana requires transcending thoughts (rationality, reasoning) and also the feeling / experiential level. Some people say that women are more of a feeling type and men are more to do with thinking (true or not I have no opinion) so in that way, someone could say that it differs for men and women. Whether you agree or not is your opinion.

Answer (score 5):

The path to nirvana does not depend on your gender but on what you follow as a human being.
Accessing nirvana is a complex thing and describing it may need pages.But,in conclusion the path to nirvana is giving up. Therefore you should understand that to "give up" things,it does not matter what your gender is.Only a person who understands the nature of human life(does not limit only to the human life, but for everything )and realize that the final result of desires and bonds only lead to the sorrow can enter into the path of nirvana.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58552/discussion-on-answer-by-i-am-feminist-who-can-realize-the-nirvana-easier).

Answer (score 1):

The path and fruition (magga phala) could be achieved by anyone, be it male or female. It could be achieved by not only the fe/male clergy but also by lay folks. There is no difference of lay and clergy for the path leading to Nibbāna. If one has selected the right system of meditation and proceeded on cultivating them the results are to be obtained with no difference for lay and clergy, male and female.

During the time of the Buddha, sixty monks realized and attained the fruition of holiness (arahant phala) having received the subjects of meditation or working ground (kammatthāna) from a **FEMALE LAY ADHERANT**  by the name Matika Matha (mother of Mathika Gama) at the village called Matika in the kingdom of Kosala.

Visaka, Cullasubadda, Queen Mallika, Samawathi, Kujjuttaa, Matikamata, Uttara, Sujata, Suppawasa, Suppiya, katiyanan, Nakulamata, Kali were some of eminent female lay disciples who were placed as great upasikas and were well praised by the Buddha.

The Dhammapada Atuwa denotes that Samawati, Kujjuttara, Matika Mata and Uttara were some of the highly praised women for their wisdom by the Buddha.

In the recent past in Sri Lanka there was **news of a female who has attained Arahant Phala.** I got to listen to a Dhamma talk given by this Buddhist Nun. She gave it because she was asked to by her Teacher (Noble Friend). After that she went out of limelight, & the glare of media. Arahants are self evasive. If someone says that he is an Arahant (as in the case of a ‘known’ Buddhist Monk in SL) then it is a questionable thing. This monk can preach the dhamma very well. Many have benefited from his sermons. But his conduct is not in keeping with that of a Arahant. What someone actually does means more than what he says, and I am not impressed by some of the things that he has done.

On the other hand this Buddhist Nun  was forced to come out. She happened to be an educated person born to a Catholic family who was raised in a Christian environment who held senior positions at work and later embraced the Buddha's Teachings. Apparently, she had the ability to see past lives and this led to a desire to study the Buddhist Teachings making her give up her lay life and ordain.  [You could listen to the talk (in SINHALA)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssK2McH3oug) along with the other monks at the temple.  Start the video at the 36 minute point to avoid the introductory talk by a bhikku at the temple where the talk is being delivered.

Comment: I wish to kiss her shoes!

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems associated with a female body, and thus it is possible that nirvana can be reached faster with a female body.

Not suggesting that ordination is the only path to nirvana but since monks can disrobe 7 times and be forgiven, but nun can only disrobe once, somehow goes to show that male body is given more chances and therefore can be slower to reach nirvana

Comment: Agreed! This is demonstrative. To show the weak nature of man and the superior Buddha nature of women.

Answer (score 0):

Five Strengths determine ability (pañcabalāni or pañca indriyāni) (or potentials) for beings to realize Nirvana.

- Faith/Conviction (saddhā bala) - controls doubt
- Energy/Effort/Persistence (viriya bala) – controls laziness
- Mindfulness (sati bala) - controls heedlessness
- Concentration (samādhi bala) - controls distraction
- Wisdom/Discernment (paññā bala) – controls ignorance

Only sammasambuddha can see strength in beings.
As far as I have read, Buddha didnt say, who has more strength; male or female.

PS. Buddha said those with ability to enter 4th Jhanna could reach Nirvana with ease.

Comment: Please kindly provide a link to where the Buddha said what you posted about the 4th jhana? Thanks

Comment: can you please provide reference in any scripture about this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "easier", ultimately, especially because the heart of Buddhist practice could be said to be "impartiality". There is just what each of us experience through the mind and body as individuals , moment by moment. There is nobody and there are no sexes ultimately, just moment by moment experiences.

The Buddha's teaching is for equality. The Buddha was against Hierarchy and the caste system. Anyone could become a monk under the Buddha but others believed that how one was born or who one was born to determined what a person had the right to do and so, they suffered.  Not, that most societies don't segregate themselves to some degree.